# BucketIterator returning labels instead of text

Tags: python, pytorch

This is what my code looks like:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Fields

label_field = Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False, batch_first=True, dtype=torch.float)
text_field = Field(tokenize='spacy', lower=True, include_lengths=True, batch_first=True)
fields = [('labels', label_field), ('Text', text_field)]

# TabularDataset

source_folder = '/dir/'
train, valid, test = TabularDataset.splits(path=source_folder, train='train.csv', validation='val.csv', test = 'test.csv',
                                           format='CSV', fields=fields, skip_header=True)

# Iterators

train_iter = BucketIterator(train, batch_size=32, sort_key=lambda x: len(x.Text),
                            device=device, sort=True, sort_within_batch=True)
valid_iter = BucketIterator(valid, batch_size=32, sort_key=lambda x: len(x.Text),
                            device=device, sort=True, sort_within_batch=True)
test_iter = BucketIterator(valid, batch_size=32, sort_key=lambda x: len(x.Text),
                            device=device, sort=True, sort_within_batch=True)

# Vocabulary

text_field.build_vocab(train, min_freq=3)
label_field.build_vocab(train, min_freq=3)
```

When I try to unpack the variables by:

```
for x in train_iter:
    print(x.Text)
```

I end up with the labels instead of the the Text, and vice versa if I try `print(x.labels)`

Comment: Did you check your original data files like `train.csv` to see if the columns are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Also, do `print(train[0])` to see if the data instance's fields are what you expect them to be.

Comment: I can't `print(train[0])`. Yes, the original data files are what I expect them to be.

Comment: I think the issue was that the correct sequence of inputs according to the dataframe wasn't followed. The dataframe had an `Unnamed: 0` column generated and I needed to include it in the `fields` variable to match the number of column headings